# Phonegap app CSS not being applied to dynamically added input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I am displaying a list of products using a layout grid and appending them after a database query.
In source code I've got:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <span id="allgarlist"></span>
</div> 
</div>
```

I then loop through the results of the query and add the rows of the grid using

```
          $('#allgarlist').append('<div class="ui-block-a" >' + '<BR><BR><img src="' + prodimgURL +  row.ImageID + '.jpg">' + ' </div><div class="ui-block-b"  >' + '<input data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" type="button" value="Select" onClick="GotoSelectedGarment(' + row.ProductId + ',' + row.IsGarment+')"/></div>');
```

This all works ok and the product image and a button to select it are displayed. My problem is that the CSS is not being applied to the button. I have tried various refresh calls but most of them just hang the app or do nothing.

What do I call to make the CSS apply to the buttons? I am just using the standard jquery mobile and phonegap css which is working fine on elements I haven't created dynamically.

thanks

Comment: Please add your CSS so we can see if the problem is in that.

Comment: Also, you really, _really_ shouldn't be appending divs to a span.

Comment: I haven't changed the CSS. It is the phonegap style.css and standard jquery mobile CSS. It is working fine on buttons that are static.
I'm assuming I need to refresh something to apply the styles to the dynamically created elements. I have tried things like giving the button an id of butt and  $('#butt').button('refresh');

Comment: WHat should I use instead of span? div doesn't work, or rather breaks the layout grid divs.

Comment: Why not just put your `allgarlist` class on the div `ui-grid-a`, and axe the span altogether.  I don't have the phonegap style.css in front of me, but seeing as there's nothing immediately apparent wrong with the code you're using, which means that it's likely not matching up to what the CSS is expecting.

Comment: I found the problem, I wasn't  refresh properly. Should have been      $('#butt').button().button('refresh');